# Is it possible to play a song in vlc player out of the command line?

Tags: linux, shell, vlc-media-player

is there a shell command in Linux (for VLC media player) to open a `*.mp3` file?

Answer (score 7):

There is also `cvlc`, the interface-less cousin of VLC. If you are running a streaming server remotely, `cvlc` is the way to go.

Comment: This is the more correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

Short Answer is yes.

The official [VLC command-line help](http://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help) wiki page can give you all the commands you need, and you should be able to just type:

```
vlc name.mp3
```

That should open the file, if you have custom devices for output you would specify that in the command line.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `vlc -I ncurses` to start a command line version of vlc.

Comment: Or `-I rc`, for something even simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Use :

`nvlc *.mp3` or `cvlc *.mp3`

The 'n' in front of 'vlc' invokes the ncurses interface in the terminal while 'c' is for the command line vlc interface, additionally you can use 
`nvlc --random /path/to/your/music` 
to play random songs from a folder.

Answer (score 0):

This command Worked for me

`vlc -I ncurses ~/Music --random`

This command plays a random song from your `/Music` folder